# How to specify a logical expression in the `value` attribute of `select` tag for further use in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, attributes

I am using PHP. Is it possible to write out a logical expression in the `value` attribute, like this:

```
<form action="...php">
<select name="formLocation" multiple>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    //Here I try to use logical expression. But it does not work:
    <option value="'DE' OR 'IL' OR 'IN'">myTerritory</option> 
</form>
```

And then the value of that option goes into mySQL query, e.g. `SELECT * FROM 'table1' WHERE 'states' LIKE '%states%'`

I want to create a unique mySQL `$query=SELECT * FROM 'table1' WHERE 'states' LIKE '%states%'` instead of specifying `myTerritory` as an exception.

*PS: I could have used the following: `SELECT * FROM 'table1' WHERE 'states' LIKE '%DE%' OR 'states' LIKE '%IL%' OR 'states' LIKE '%IN%'`
But this would over complicate the code for a more complex search...*

Comment: what exactly is the problem? do you have any exception/

Comment: What are the possible values for the `states` column? Is a string of state values? One per row? Or multiple per row?

Comment: @John Conde state column is varchar, max length is 2. values are the regular state codes: AL, AK, AZ ...etc.

Comment: @JW The problem is mySQL query brings 0 results...I am not sure it is possible to include a logical expression in the value attribute. I have never done this. I searched the web...I could not find anybody using this. The final query should look like `$query=SELECT * FROM 'table1' WHERE 'states' LIKE ('DE' OR 'IL' OR 'IN')` but it gets messed up with those apostrophes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `<select>` allows multiple selections you just need to change the name to allow an array of data to be sent to PHP:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<select name="formLocation[]" multiple>
```

You can then use [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in PHP and [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) in MySQL.  *Make sure you are santizing your input or using parameterized queries! Not shown here!*

```
<?php
$states = implode(',', $_POST['formLocation']);
?>

// your query
SELECT * FROM 'table1' WHERE 'states' IN($states)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to rethink your model a little bit. It sounds like there's a relationship between State and Territory, and you might want your tables to reflect that.

Perhaps your table might look something like this:

```
State:
+----------------------------+-------+
| abbreviation | territoryId | sales |
+----------------------------+-------+
|           AL |           1 |   300 |
|           AK |           2 |   350 |
|           DE |           3 |   250 |
|           IN |           3 |   100 |
|           IL |           3 |   200 |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

Then your form could be simplified as follows:

```
<form action="...php">
<select name="formLocation" multiple>
    <option value="1">My Territory</option>
    <option value="2">Your Territory</option>
    <option value="3">Her Territory</option>
</form>
```

And your query would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(sales) FROM State WHERE territoryId = 3;
```

This makes a much better use of MySQL as a relational database. Of course, there's probably a lot more going on with your model, but hopefully this is a start.